# Another way to refer members in a structure

Tags: c++

Now, I am learning as to how to use structures properly in `C++`.
Is there another way to refer members in a structure.

As an example, below is my code.
I want to know if I can do something like `test.b` to refer `name` member in the structure.

Is there any incredible way to do so?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
 {
    string name = "Test";
 };

int main()
{
    A test;
    string b = "name";


    cout << test.name;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: To clarify do you want to load the name of a `struct` member into a variable and use then access that named member by way of the variable? Short version is: you can't, c++ has very limited reflection.

Comment: Use `std::map` if you really need to do this

Comment: Thanks very much!
I will look into std::map...

Comment: should that be `test.b` instead of `test.name` at the bottom of main?  otherwise I don't think there's much of a question here

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to use a string to reference the member then the way to do this is called "pointer to member":

```
struct A
{
  int name;
  int value;
};

main()
{
  int A::* b = &A::name; // assign "name" to the variable called b

  struct A test = {1,2}; // make a structure and fill it in

  return test.*b;        // use the variable called b to reference test.name
}
```

If you do need to refennce the items with a string the other way mentioned in the contents is to use a map.  That can be useful if all your members are the same type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

main()
{
  std::map<std::string,int> test; // make something that can be keyed by a string

  test["name"]=1; // put something called "name" in the map with a value of 1
  test["value"]=2; // put something called "value" in the map with a value of 2

  std::cout << test["name"] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For OP's reference, the first version is called "pointer to member"

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 3):

What you are referring to is called `Reflection` (function/attribute access by name). C++ by default doesn't have reflection. So probably you need to look for libraries/frameworks for that. Google "C++ Reflection" for that. Boost is one of the solution out there for C++ reflection/serialization.

Comment: Thanks very much. I did not know my question actually has a name. I will google it and see if I can find one..

Comment: In case you haven't found any useful/comprehensive info, I found this really useful http://indico.cern.ch/event/048/session/4/contribution/185/material/slides/2.pdf

Comment: I worked on a project that makes use of reflex under the hood. It works, but the code generation step adds a pinch of magic to the build that can be very annoying at times.